# Is <!DOCTYPE html> an html tag?

Tags: html

I see that HTML tags start with a `<` and end with a `>`
 So, is `<!DOCTYPE html>` a HTML tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[HTML 5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#tags) defines:

> **Tags** are used to delimit the start and end of elements in the markup.

The Doctype does not delimit an element. So no, it is not a tag.

[It is](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype):

> a required preamble

Comment: Very helpful to me!